# Remove the llvm-clang tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I don't get the purpose of having

- [clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang)
- [llvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/llvm)
- [llvm-clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/llvm-clang)

I find this rather confusing, shouldn't [llvm-clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/llvm-clang) be deleted (I suppose "*burninated*" is the correct term from what I've read around)?

Most likely every question asked can either have the [clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang), [llvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/llvm) or both tags.

Comment: @HansPassant Okay, but there are [several questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/llvm-clang) using the `llvm-clang` tag. I believe asking here would be the correct and polite approach of doing it

Comment: I'd add that many only use the llvm-clang tag and not the other two. It will be a bit of a work to get which one of the remaining two (or both) should be added to retag all those questions.

Comment: what is difference between `llvm-clang` and `clang`?

Comment: I initially guessed one of them might be for use of the front end in other tools, but we appear to have `libclang` for that. The tag wikis don't indicate a significant difference.

Comment: I agree with Leuschenko, `llvm-clang` and `clang` seem to be the same.

Comment: This is still a problem, two years later? Woah. (Unfortunately, I don't have the tag-specific reputation to suggest the synonym. Y'all?)

Answer (score 1):

There are 716 questions, at the moment, using [llvm-clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/llvm-clang); so, editing them to replace that tag with [clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang) would require enough time, considering that we should avoid to bump too much old questions on the front page.

The tags need to be merged, since their wikis suggest their purpose is the same.

> For questions about the clang LLVM compiler front end. For general questions about C, use the C tag.

> Clang is the C language family front-end for the LLVM compiler. (The C language family includes C, C++, Objective-C, and Objective-C++.)

There is no need to have *llvm* in the tag name: CLang is the compiler front-end for LLVM.

Comment: "considering that we should avoid to bump too much old questions on the front page" this is, yet again, not an issue. The home page has enough entropy for anyone to take notice of 100 edited questions.

Comment: 100 questions are nothing, compared to 700 questions. Also, that was the general suggestion given about editing questions to removed a tag. After all, the possibility to merge tags was thought for those cases where editing questions to fix a tag would take too much time, maybe also because new users keep using the wrong tag.

Comment: Unless you can more than 100 questions in a hour, the sheer size of SO would drown your edits. In fact, the only ones that would see all your edits would be those watching /active and those would have also mixed in those edited, answered and new asked questions mixed in too.

Comment: Still, they made available a tool appositely for merging two tags without the need to edit every question using one of them. Together with the tool to make them synonym, it avoids editing questions for the mere purpose of removing a single tag.