# Should [llvm-clang] be a synonym of [clang]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

I found this question asking about [removing the `llvm-clang` tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276157/9614249) from last year. The community seemed to agree that combining the tags was a good idea but nothing appears to have happened.

Questions under both tags refer to clang and often both tags are included on the same question. The description for each tag also implies there is no difference between the two.

#### `clang`

> For questions about the clang LLVM compiler front end. For general questions about C, use the C tag.

#### `llvm-clang`

> Clang is the C language family front-end for the LLVM compiler. (The C language family includes C, C++, Objective-C, and Objective-C++.)

As of today there are nearly 6,000 `clang` questions and 800 `llvm-clang` questions so re-tagging would by a lot of work, but marking `llvm-clang` as a synonym of clang should be an easy fix right?

Comment: The tag wiki for [llvm-clang] is rather poor.  These are two very distinct chunks of code with very different skill sets required to do anything with them.  If nobody edits it in the next few days then I'll take a stab at it.

Comment: @HansPassant what is the difference between the two? Most questions I see with the `llvm-clang` tag seems to have used it by mistake when they meant either `llvm` or `clang`.

Comment: [clang] is the front end, it has the parser.  [llvm-clang] is the back-end, it has the code generator and optimizer.  Very different jobs and two distinct projects.  I don't know exactly by how much [llvm] was customized to make it fit [clang], but enough to give it its own name.